# In Skyfall, was the bar scene a daydream or was it real?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, skyfall

Early in the movie Skyfall, when Bond is presumed dead, he is shown drinking at a bar and being cheered on by a large group of spectators as he attempts to down a drink with a live scorpion on his hand.  Immediately as this scene ends, Bond is shown at the same bar, but the bar is now empty except for the bartender.

When I originally saw the movie, I thought the quick cut was meant to show that it was the next day, and that Bond had spent the entire night at the bar.  However, I have seen some speculate that the first scene was merely a daydream - Bond imagining how he would like his life to be, when in reality he spends his time drinking alone in the middle of the day.

**Could someone explain whether it was a daydream or not?**

Comment: Interesting question but I would go with the first thought.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is more likely to have been real imho.   Bond is superficially charasmatic and able to make shallow relationships with ease, like his ability to seduce women.

However, he has issues forming deep relationships with anyone.  His relationships with women usually end quickly with little emotional connection.

It is the same in the bar, one minute he is able to impress everyone and become the centre of attention but none of them are actually his friends and he quickly ends up alone again.

Comment: Getting laid all the time. The life of a party. Hot woman. Carry a gun. Yea, it's a tough life.

Comment: Well I gave no comment on whether Bond likes his life overall :-)  Merely that the scene in the bar is a reflection of how he can quickly develop shallow relationships but ends up alone at the end of it with no real friends.  The psychological weight of what he has to do (often reflected in his heavy drinking) would probably require that he shut down a lot of the more humane parts of his brain (e.g. at the end of Casino Royal he insists on the continued torture of Matthis in case he was a traitor) and try not to feel anything for others

Comment: I thought the most interesting part of Skyfall was the MI6 psyche profile of Bond confirmed he is an alcoholic with major psychological issues. This coupled with the drinking scene plus the talk of his orphan childhood suggests that underneath the super-cool surface, he is a tortured soul.

Answer (score 7):

**The scene at the beach bar was real.** The change from crowded night to empty day shows that Bond's drinking binge lasted all night. He wasn't there to party like the other patrons -- he was there to get blind drunk.

Bond went on the drinking binge because he was upset at M for having Eve shoot at Patrice. Bond explains this to M when he comes back to MI6. He says something like "I couldn't believe you didn't trust me to finish the mission."

Bond's anger stems from how M is a mother-figure to Bond (a key theme of *Skyfall*). When M ordered the shot, Bond felt something akin to rejection or violation of trust. He was thinking something like "M was one of the few people I thought I could trust, but even she isn't reliable, so what's the point of anything? I might as well just get wasted and get laid."

Answer (score 0):

You guys are making this all WAAAAAY too complicated.  The drinking scene was nighttime.  He stayed in the bar all night and into the morning, by which time everyone had gone home.  There's nothing even remotely dreamlike about anything in that scene.